# How exactly does a basic EMF sensor work?

Tags: arduino, wireless, electromagnetic, emf

Halloween is coming up, and inspired by the simplicity of [this project](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/PatelDarshil/arduino-emf-detector-a-k-a-ghost-detector-7ce085), I'm asking for a more technical explanation (and / or resources to do that) - this seems to be either missing or too obvious to explain.

The premise is simple: come up with a device to measure 'electromagnetic waves', e.g. in wifi spectrum, 2.4GHz or something emitting from a powerline, here, ca 200-220V at 60Hz (unsure what frequency that would equate to). Somehow, here, this is achieved by only a resistor and an open circuit.

I know Ohm's law `U=R*I` and, from what I read, the sensitivity increases (at least monotonically increasingly) with the resistor value (e.g. 10k less sensitive than 1mOhm).

Questions:

1. How exactly does this measure EMF, and is it possible to measure multiple frequencies, by simply attaching multiple loose wires (and does the thickness matter?)
2. What is the role of the resistor and how does it help to measure the signals properly? Can we explain the sensitivity of this sensor by Ohm's law, i.e. a linear relationship?

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
// code used on the cited project, all credit goes to the author Patel Darshil
int inPin = 5;             // analog 5 
int val = 0;                 // where to store info from analog 5
int pin11 = 11;         // output of red led

void setup() {
 
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
}

void loop() {
  
  val = analogRead(inPin);                    // reads in the values from analog 5 and
                                                                   //assigns them to val
  if(val >= 1){
    
    val = constrain(val, 1, 100);               // mess with these values                                       
    val = map(val, 1, 100, 1, 255);        // to change the response distance of the device
    analogWrite(pin11, val);                    // *note also messing with the resistor should change  
                                                                   // the sensitivity
   }else{                                                     // analogWrite(pin11, val); just tuns on the led with 
                                                                  // the intensity of the variable val
    analogWrite(pin11, 0);                     // the else statement is just telling the microcontroller
                                                                 // to turn off the light if there is no EMF detected
  }
  
 Serial.println(val);                                // use output to aid in calibrating
 
}
```

Comment: keep in mind that I'm a beginner in electronics (and I can't make sense of the Wikipedia article).

Comment: I hate projects like this. Not providing a schematic to a project is not conducive to understanding of anyone trying to attempt it. But it's basically just detecting noise on the antenna. Noise in the air will drive charges into or out of the wire the same way you empty or fill a bucket with water (as opposed to continuous current flow in a loop which is more like water flowing continously in a pipe). This moving charge is a current and since it flows through the resistor produces a voltage drop across it which is sensed by the ADC pin.

Comment: @user2305193, the project you referred seems not explaining what is going on. The LED you show in you picture seems an Infra red detector. Let me see if I can explain at middle shcool physics level.

(1) EMF stands for Electromagnet Frequency/Wave which has a range of different wave lengths.
(2) We human eyes can detect a frequency range of the whole frequency spectrum which is called visible light. 
(3) Very briefly, Infra red is in a range we human eyes can not detect.
(4) But we can use IR detector to detect IR
 
/ to continue, ...

Comment: / cont, ... I know you don't like to read Wikipedia. But perhaps you can skim my answer (with a lot of photos and images) to an IR question to get a rough idea of what is going on. There is a list of references of the photos you are interested. So from a photo in my answer, you can read the associated reference and see more photos/images. 

This is the link to my IR answer "... UART IR Transceiver Setup" https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103452/rpi3-lirc-library-and-uart-ir-transceiver-setup-problem. Happy reading. Cheers.

Comment: From my answer, you can see that your TV remote is an IR transmitter, and the TV set has an IR receiver. You can also find from the photo which has an IR receiver looking similar to yours and go to the reference list to find more description of the IR receiver device. You mention 2.4GHz, actually there are other frequency ranges with similar operation, transmitter and receiver devices..

Comment: @tlfong01 no, the LED is not connected to the input. only an antenna is connected there.

Comment: @Jasen, Many thanks for pointing out my careless mistake. I forgot that it is ***Hallloween Ghost Detector***. So the red LED blinking indicating a 2.4GHz Ghost is detected. I also did not notice any antenna. So I was wrong to assume that it is a IR project. My apologies again.

Comment: ***Apology and Update*** - Now I know that Halloween Ghost talks at 2.4G, or they have upgraded to Mobile 5G, which is 2.2GHz. I am not sure if I remember the numbers correctly. So I revised my cheatsheet: 
https://i.imgur.com/y1lcsrN.jpeg

Comment: Halloween Ghost Frequency - So the ghosts talk at radio frequency around 2.4G. Actually Blue Tooth is also 2.4GHz. So the IR project I was talking earlier is wrong. What I recommend now is the nRF24L01+ 2.4GHz transmitter. ***How can Rpi communicate with Arduino in RF (Radio Frequency)?*** - Rpi SE 2020mar02
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108959/how-can-rpi-communicate-with-arduino-in-rf-radio-frequency the ghosts should be loving it. Cheers

Comment: Hi, I added a clarifying picture, as the setup wasn't super clear. The LED is simply the indicator (as the arduino code and video reveals), whatever is measured with the antenna is converted using ADC from the arduino, as @DKNguyen points out correctly! I took the libery of adding tlfong01's cheat-sheet

Comment: @user2305193, Ah, your clarification is good. Earlier I did not notice the antenna and thought the white LED was an IR detector. By the way, if your detector can detect 2.4GHz signal, and BlueTooth is also 2.4GHz, I wonder if you can use your smart phone to send some BlueTooth signals pretending the Haloween Ghosts are talking?

Comment: that would be great xD I doubt it would work well I must say. I think this version is supposed to detect the ghosts 'in the wall', i.e. the AC current flowing there and their emitted EMF. Understanding either version better would work for me =)

Comment: @user2305193, Ha, I misunderstood your question. (1) You first mentioned "***2.4GHz***" or "***something emitting from a power line, ... 200-220V at 60Hz***". Your first photo showed a white LED thing, so I wrongly thought that it was an IR receiver. (2) Then your second photo showed an antenna, and I wrongly thought the antenna was for 2.4GHz. So I recommend the 2.4GHz nRFL2401+ transmitter/receiver. (3) Now you clarified that the antenna is to pickup the power line EMF noise. So I would now try to see how you can pick up power line noise (220~240VAC, 50/60Hz). I need to google again, :).

Comment: Now we have a very tight schedule because Halloween comes Oct31. I agree with @glen_geek in his answer, saying that your Arduino ADC pin connected short wire antenna cannot detect 2.4GHz or other radio frequency signals. But I am not sure if it can detect the walls' AC power line 50/60Hz signal when placed near the wall. You remind me what my grandmother told me, long long time ago: Our Chinese ghosts (actually our ancestors) come out in July, and when they come out, they hop along the wall. / to continue, ...

Comment: So we children are reminded during Ghost Festival to say "***Excuse me, Excuse me***" when walking near the wall, so the "Yin Qi" ghosts coming out from the Yin World would be alerted and not bump into we "Yang Qi" children. Anyway, I will forget 2.4GHz and google line noise. Cheers.

Comment: @user2305193, So I made a quick and dirty antenna, captured a ghost wave, uploaded here for your viewing pleasure. Next step is to connect the antenna to a Rpi GPIO pin and see if my Rpi4B can read the signal. Ah, locking down supper time. See you later.

Comment: I did some following up test, such as shortening the antenna wire from 2 metres to 30 cm, change the 10M resistor to 1M etc, the picked up line signal/noise becomes smaller, but still of order 200mV. / to continue, ...

Comment: So I think we can easily use an audio power amplifier to amplify the signal and output to a speaker. In other words, even Arduino is not required. Of course we can do more fancier things with Arduino, such as after detecting the AC signal, using text-to-speech to output human/ghost voice. Unluckily our schedule is too tight to do these fancy things.  So my answer stops here.  Have a great Halloween project, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

The *ATMega168 data sheet* is the primary reference to see electrical characteristics of an Analog-to-Digital input pin. Even so, the data sheet does not show some components that are probably relevant to this strange application.
 In the OP's source document, no claims are made for what kind of input signals might evoke a change in the ADC result.

In answer to your question2:
 The 10k resistor between Analog input pin and GND likely dominates, providing a digital ADC result near zero. A higher value than 10k will very likely increase the ADC result above zero (increased signal sensitivity), but will decrease intensity of the connected LED.
The ADC input pins have this internal circuit (from ATMEega168 data sheet). \$I_{IL}\$ is likely leakage current - a very small value:
[image: ATMega168 Analog input pin circuit]
Not shown in this schematic is **input pin protection network** which includes diode clamps to prevent input voltage from exceeding DC supply voltage, and exceeding GND voltage. These diodes may be important when an input pin contains radio frequency signals. Any voltage detected by these diodes is passed into the **ADCn** input pin. The other diode connected to the input pin is the LED...not a very effective detector of radio frequency signals.
The internal RC network filters out most radio frequency components - certainly any 2.5 GHz signals. 
The user is cautioned that internally-generated switching signals can affect the ADC result. These signals likely have a noise effect through their very close proximity to the internal analog circuitry. This noise source can be reduced (again, from ATMega168 data sheet):

> **21.5.2 Analog Noise Canceling Techniques**
>  Digital circuitry inside and outside the device generates EMI which might affect the
> accuracy of analog measurements. If conversion accuracy is critical,
> the noise level can be reduced by applying the following
> techniques:
>
> - a. Keep analog signal paths as short as possible. Make sure analog tracks run over the analog ground plane, and keep them well away from
>   high-speed switching digital tracks.
> - b. The AVCC pin on the device should be connected to the digital VCC supply voltage via an LC network as shown in Figure 21-9.
> - c. Use the ADC noise canceler function to reduce induced noise from the CPU.
> - d. If any ADC [3..0] port pins are used as digital outputs, it is essential that these do not switch while a conversion is in progress.
>   However, using the 2-wire interface (ADC4 and ADC5) will only affect
>   the conversion on ADC4 and ADC5 and not the other ADC channels.

Is is possible to measure multiple frequencies?
Very unlikely. Since radio signal amplitude is detected *before* ADC input, frequency is unkownable. However, the short antenna favours higher-frequency radio signals over lower-frequency signals. Not a very good discriminator of frequency.

Note that an open-circuit input pin generally has a *very* high input resistance, limited only by leakage currents. An "antenna" wire connected to such a pin can be influenced by DC electric fields that change. Do ghosts exhale electric fields? A hand (perhaps connected to a charged body) waved over such a wire can change the logic state of that input pin. This is *not* a detector of radio signals. A 100k resistor added in series to such a wire would be a good precaution.

Answer (score 2):

***Question***

*How to detect power line 110~220VAC 50/60Hz noise (sort of Halloween Ghost radio wave)?*

---

***Answer***

***Update 2020oct26hkt0022***

I now think that the OP's problem might be the following:

(1) His antenna is too short.  I used ***2 metres long dangling wire with 10MΩ resistor*** soldered at one end and can get 400mV 50Hz signal.  Even 200mV with 30cm 10MΩ resistor.

(2) I placed the antenna within 2 metres of the AC power line (hidden inside wall).  If the OP's place has the power line too high above ground, then the signal might be very weak.

(3) So if using a long wire as antenna, and the OP gets more than 100mV with the Arduino ADC pin, the problem might have been solved.  The OP can then consider using an audio power amplifier to amplifier and output to a loudspeaker.

---

*Part A - Making a 50Hz antenna*

*I made the following quick and dirty antenna - 2 metre long connected wire, with a 10MΩ soldered at one end.*

---

*Part B - Checking ghost noise picked up by the antenna*

*I used my USD300, 30MHz, 4 Channel Digital Storage Oscilloscope to display the waveform at one end of the dangling wire/antenna, got the ghost signal, screen captured it and download to a USB finger, displayed it in my Win10 PC and finally uploaded to this EE SE forum.*

---

[image: ac line noise 1]

---

*Part C - My original plan was to input this 50Hz, 400 mV peak to peak to Arduino ADC pin and let Arduino to do the ADC and subsequent data processing.*

However, on second thought, if we already got a 400mV signal, actually we can use any audio power amplifier to amplify the signal and output to a loudspeaker to hear the low frequency humming sound.

Of course we can also use Arduino to detect the AC 50 Hz signal and do some fancy things, such as use text-to-speech utility to output human voice.

Another fancy thing is to treat the 50Hz signal as a carrier wave and do amplitude modulation, similar to AM radio transmission, except that our 50Hz amplitude modulation signal operates indoor, in other words, cannot be broadcast outdoor.  So strictly speaking, this 50Hz signal is not "radio" signal.

---